# Angular sub-views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I google a bit about the topic but I couldn't get a clear answer on the subject, so apologies if this seems a pretty beaten down question. I've started with Angular not long ago, and I really want to be on the good path.

The application is bootstraped by `app.js` which defines the routes in the configuration. The `index.html` has a body with a `ng-app` directive an just a div inside with a `ng-view`.

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

This `main.html` and controller are the bulk of the app, which is quite simple.

Now I wanted to have a header, which either shows Login or the information from the user. I though that should be another Controller and another View, since the header should encapsulate all that code instead of polluting the main view.

What should I do?

1. I could remove the `ng-app` and create two different controllers for the header and the main app, but then I don't know how to associate each view to each `ng-controller` like the `routeProvider` is doing, although if I don't mind writing all the html inline, this should work. I would also lose routing which I don't really want to.
2. I could just create a `ng-controller=headerController` inside the app and still have the code inline. Is there an option to associate a template with a controller without the route definition?

What I'm currently going to do until I have a better option is to add all of this logic to the mainController. I just feel that I'm building big blocks instead of small ones that I can just  compose. Imagine I do three more routes that need a header. Using option 1) or 2) I would have to write the template html for the header again in those views.

I would appreciate any links or help for this matter, I'm really curious how to approach this in a module fashion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could remove the ng-app and create two different controllers for the header and the main app, but then I don't know how to associate each view to each ng-controller like the routeProvider is doing, although if I don't mind writing all the html inline, this should work. I would also lose routing which I don't really want to.

You will just write two different modules which have the same `routeConfig` and things will probably work. However, I do not think that it is the best solution in this case.

To answer your second question:

> I could just create a `ng-controller=headerController` inside the app and still have the code inline. Is there an option to associate a template with a controller without the route definition?

You can use `ng-include` to include the template:

```html
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <section ng-include="'header.html'" ng-controller="HeaderController"></section>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

Moreover, you can keep the template inline by using either the `$templateCache` or by using [`<script>` tag](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script).

Comment: Thank you. This seems pretty much what I need, is this a hack or ng-include was built for this purpose? I'll be happy to accept this as correct answer (already +1) as soon as I test it out.

Comment: `ng-include` is a general way of inserting partials. `ng-view` indeed is limited because it can be bound only once and it is generally worked around by using `ng-include` in this way. You can also look at [`ui-route`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) if you need to switch views depending on routes, but since it is _pre-beta_, you should not use it in production code yet.

Comment: A lot of people talk about the ui-route, a lot of stars in github. I will adopt your approach and fallback to ui-route if I need something better. For changes inside the header, I will use angular's if directive, for example to distinguish a logged in from a logged out user. thanks, accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-include to insert your template.  I personally like to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)